# How can I only show one data label per donut chart in my stacked donut chart graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have the following Python code for producing a stacked pie chart using Matplotlib:

*[Note: If this code is eligible for copyright (since it's mostly based on Matplotlib documentation), I release it not only under the CC-BY-SA license (required by Stack Overflow), but also under the MIT license.]*

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

size = 0.5 
inner_radius = 1

ax.pie(stat_1, labels = label_1, radius = inner_radius, startangle = 90,
autopct  = '%1.1f%%', pctdistance = 1-(1/(4*inner_radius)), colors = colors, 
normalize=False, wedgeprops= {'width': size*0.9, 'edgecolor': 'w'}) 

ax.pie(stat_2, labels = label_2, radius = inner_radius+size, startangle = 90, 
autopct = '%1.1f%%', pctdistance = 1-(1/(4*(inner_radius+size))), colors = 
colors, normalize=False, wedgeprops= {'width': size*0.9, 'edgecolor': 'w'})


ax.pie(stat_3, labels = label_3, radius = inner_radius+2*size, startangle = 90, 
autopct = '%1.1f%%', pctdistance = 1-(1/(4*(inner_radius+2*size))), colors = 
colors, normalize=False, wedgeprops= {'width': size*0.9, 'edgecolor': 'w'})

ax.legend(loc=[-0.5, 1])
```

Here is the stacked donut chart that the code produces:

[image]

Right now, there are two data labels per chart (one for the red area and one for the gray area), but I'd like only the data labels in the red chart sections to show. How can I remove the data labels in the gray chart sections (or prevent them from appearing)?

If need be, I can separate the gray sections into separate plots, but I'd like to find a simpler solution if possible.

Comment: One simple solution would be to make the data labels the 
same color as the gray wedges, causing them to only be visible within the red wedges. But I'd prefer to have white labels and gray wedges if possible.

Similarly, I could make the wedges white, change the edge colors to black (so that the currently gray wedges remain visible), and then make the data labels white.

Comment: You may not specify a preferred license when posting questions. See [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, in that case, do I have the right as the author of the code to use it later on in an MIT-licensed program or a program using another license? I wouldn't want to be forced to release a program using this code under the CC-BY-SA 4.0 license.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the specifics of all the licenses.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney The answer below indicates that I am allowed to release code posted on Stack Overflow under a secondary license (e.g. the MIT license). Is there any source that says I am not allowed to release code under both CC-BY-SA 4.0 and the MIT license? I also updated the text in my original post to specify that the MIT license is one of two licenses under which I am releasing the code.
https://law.stackexchange.com/a/50231/37035